# No armeabi folder

Tags: android, android-library, sqlcipher, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I´m trying to integrate SQLCipher with my android application. I´m getting the following error when running the app:

**java.lang.Unsatisfiedlinkerror Couln´t load stlport_shared: find library returned NULL**

The thing is i have already add to my classpath the following JARS

commons-codec.jar

guava-r09.jar

sqlcipher.jar

**In the instructions it says, u have to add 3 .os files into armeabi folder inside libs, but in my libs folder I only have android-suppor-v4.jar**

What do I have to do? Any ideas?

Regards!

Comment: _"but in my libs folder I only have android-suppor-v4.jar"_ You probably need to add armeabi and x86 folders under libs, unless they're already present, and put the stlport library there. The same way [they've done here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/tree/master/libs)

Comment: Ok, but i just have to copy these folders inside libs? I don´t have to give some special treatment to these folders (armeabi and X86) ? I´m going to try it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the help of Micheal I have solved the issue.

There was no armeabi folder inside "libs". I have to create here the same structure as in this link https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/tree/master/libs

Then, you have to add to your build path the 3 jar files, and in the folder assests you have to copy the .zip file that is in there too.

That solved the problem, and now the database is working fine with SQLCipher.

Thanks you!